# How can I convert OData to ServiceStack AutoQuery?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I have a Web API project that uses OData to query the database. But now I want to transform this project using ServiceStack AutoQuery. The problem is that I **don't** have access to the frontend. So the incomming requests are using the OData filter expressions. Is there a way to transform the ODataQueryOptions so I can query that database using AutoQuery or OrmLite?

**Edit (@mythz):**

so I should transform the url to an OrmLite query? For example:

```
Categories?$filter=(Id eq 11) and (Deleted eq false)&$expand=CategoryTranslations
```

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Category> Categories(ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions)
{
    var query = ErpDb.From<Category>();

    #region ordering

    if (odataQueryOptions.OrderBy != null)
    {
        query.UnsafeOrderBy(odataQueryOptions.OrderBy.RawValue);
    }

    #endregion

    #region paging

    var inlineCount = ErpDb.Count(query);

    if (odataQueryOptions.Skip != null)
    {
        query.Skip(odataQueryOptions.Skip.Value);
    }

    if (odataQueryOptions.Top != null)
    {
        query.Take(odataQueryOptions.Top.Value);
    }

    #endregion


    ...
}
```

Comment: I think one way is to write your own converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoQuery RDBMS](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) uses OrmLite to query an RDBMS directly, so you'd need to essentially query OData APIs to populate an InMemory SQLite database on Startup.

Alternatively you can use an [AutoQuery Memory Data Source](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-memory) to call a 3rd Party API and return a List of POCOs which you can then query with AutoQuery, e.g:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryDataFeature { MaxLimit = 100 }
    .AddDataSource(ctx => ctx.MemorySource(() =>  
      $"https://host/{ctx.Request.GetParam("table")}?{MyODataQuery(ctx.Request)}"
       .GetJsonFromUrl(req => req.UserAgent="AutoQuery").FromJson<List<Model>>(),
      HostContext.LocalCache, 
      TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
);
```

The example also shows how you can cache the results to improve performance.

Comment: I've did an edit on my original question.

Comment: @Nesse Your question doesn't looks like it's using AutoQuery, it's just using OrmLite to implement an OData API which I'm assuming could work if you return `ErpDb.Select<Category>` or `ErpDb.LoadSelect<Category>` to include POCO references.

Comment: For now I only can change the backend and I was wondering what would be the best approach. In the end I will alter the whole project using AutoQuery as API platform.

Comment: How should I handle multi-level includes? I know that OrmLite only goes 1 level down when using LoadSelect. `$expand=StockItems/StockUnits/WarehouseLocation`

Comment: @Nesse Only way would be to create a [Custom AutoQuery impl](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) to populate any additional DTO Data manually, [Merging POCO results](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/reference-support.html#merge-disconnected-poco-result-sets) may be useful for this.